# Changing a Blueprint MultiSelect input placeholder text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blueprintjs

I am looking for a way to replace the "Search..." default input string. Looking through the Blueprint Labs docs for the [MultiSelect component](http://blueprintjs.com/docs/#labs/multi-select) (and [example page](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/blob/master/packages/labs/examples/multiSelectExample.tsx)) I am unable to find a way to set the rendered input's placeholder text. I had assumed it would work similar to the Suggest component but allowing for an inputProps pass thru, but that doesn't seem to work. Here's my sample code:

```
<MultiSelect inputProps={{placeholder: "Search for a country"}} ...otherProps />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `tagInputProps`.

```
<MultiSelect
   tagInputProps={{ placeholder: 'Search for a country' }}
   itemRenderer={this.foo}
   tagRenderer={this.foo}
   items={[]}
   selectedItems={[]}
   onItemSelect={this.bar}
 />
```

Works as expected

[image]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17668195)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I expanded my answer

Comment: BTW: `inputProps` for `Select` & `Suggest`